# Is there a C99 data type guaranteed to be at least two bytes?

Tags: c, memory, types, c99, endianness

To determine the endianness of a system, I plan to store a **multi-byte** integer value in a variable and access the **first byte** via an `unsigned char` wrapped in a `union`; for example:

```
union{
    unsigned int val;
    unsigned char first_byte;
} test;

test.val = 1; /* stored in little-endian system as "0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00" */

if(test.first_byte == 1){
    printf("Little-endian system!");
}else{
    printf("Big-endian system!");
}
```

I want to make this test portable across platforms, but I'm not sure if the C99 standard guarantees that the `unsigned int` data type will be greater than **one byte** in size. Furthermore, since a "C byte" does not technically have to be 8-bits in size, I cannot use exact width integer types (e.g. `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, etc.).

Are there any C data types guaranteed by the C99 standard to be at least two bytes in size?

**P.S.** Assuming an `unsigned int` is in fact greater than one byte, would my `union` behave as I'm expecting (with the variable `first_byte` accessing the first byte in variable `val`) across all C99 compatible platforms?

Comment: just a side-question: why do you want to detect the endianness at run-time? it's unlikely to have (compiled) code running at different platforms and thus a precompiler macro like `__BIG_ENDIAN__` or `__LITTLE_ENDIAN__` should be sufficient ...

Comment: @akira I'm writing variables to a binary file which I would like to read portably across platforms; i.e. the file may be generated on a little-endian system, but transfered to and read on a big-endian system.

Comment: It is simpler, and barely measurably slower, simply to read and write the data in a standardized format on all machines.  It cuts down on the number of versions of the code that have to be tested, which makes the software more reliable, all other things being equal.

Comment: @VilhelmGray: use `network byte order` when storing binary files (and the helper functions `ntoh`, `ntohl` etc). much less hassle. or use some serialization library such as http://s11n.net/c11n/ or protobufs etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `int` must have a range of at least 16 bits, `int` will meet your criterion on most practical systems.  So would `short` (and `long`, and `long long`).  If you want exactly 16 bits, you have to look to see whether `int16_t` and `uint16_t` are declared in `<stdint.h>`.

If you are worried about systems where `CHAR_BIT` is greater than 8, then you have to work harder.  If `CHAR_BIT` is 32, then only `long long` is guaranteed to hold two characters.

---

#### What the C standard says about sizes of integer types

In a comment, [Richard J Ross III](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) says:

> The standard says absolutely nothing about the size of an int except that it must be larger than or equal to short, so, for example, it could be 10 bits on some systems I've worked on.

On the contrary, the C standard has specifications on the lower bounds on the ranges that must be supported by different types, and a system with 10-bit `int` would not be conformant C.

Specifically, in ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §5.2.4.2.1 **Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`**, it says:

> ¶1 The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions suitable for use in `#if`
>   preprocessing directives. Moreover, except for `CHAR_BIT` and `MB_LEN_MAX`, the
>   following shall be replaced by expressions that have the same type as would an
>   expression that is an object of the corresponding type converted according to the integer
>   promotions. Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude
>   (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
>
> — number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)
>     `CHAR_BIT 8`
>
> [...]
>
> — minimum value for an object of type `short int`
>
> `SHRT_MIN -32767` // −(2<sup>15</sup> − 1)
>
> — maximum value for an object of type `short int`
>
> `SHRT_MAX +32767` // 2<sup>15</sup> − 1
>
> — maximum value for an object of type `unsigned short int`
>
> `USHRT_MAX 65535` // 2<sup>16</sup> − 1
>
> — minimum value for an object of type `int`
>
> `INT_MIN -32767` // −(2<sup>15</sup> − 1)
>
> — maximum value for an object of type `int`
>
> `INT_MAX +32767` // 2<sup>15</sup> − 1
>
> — maximum value for an object of type `unsigned int`
>
> `UINT_MAX 65535` // 2<sup>16</sup> − 1

Comment: The standard says absolutely nothing about the size of an int except that it must be larger than  or equal to `short`, so, for example, it could be 10 bits on some systems I've worked on.

Comment: That why there is typdef like uint_least16_t, this way the code is portable and there is no performance penalty (using a 16 bits integer on a 32 or 64 bits computer can decrease performance in some case)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Those are strange bits if you can represent the range `[-32767 .. +32767]` in them (that is the minimum range of values that `int` must support).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII If a short has to have at least 2 bytes (which the standard does mandate, at least implicitly, by giving `short`s a minimum range that can't be achieved in less than 2 bytes) and an `int` must be larger than or equal to `short`, then clearly it could not be 10 bits on any system.

Comment: @Richard: no, `short` is 16 bits minimum, the problem is there's no maximum for `char`.

Comment: @sepp2k: As the C standard does not require a byte to be identical to an octet, there is nothing stopping a `short` from being one byte long (you just need 16-bit bytes then)

Comment: `int` must be at least 16 bits, but that has no relation to the number of bytes in the C sense of byte (which is just another name for `char`).

Answer (score 4):

GCC provides some macros giving the endianness of a system: [GCC common predefined macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html)

example (from the link supplied):

```
/* Test for a little-endian machine */
#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
```

Of course, this is only useful if you use gcc. Furthermore, conditional compilation for endianness can be considered harmful. Here is a nice article about this: [The byte order fallacy](http://commandcenter.blogspot.jp/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html).

I would prefer to do this using regular condtions to let the compiler check the other case. ie:

```
if (__BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

No, nothing is guaranteed to be larger than one byte -- but it is guaranteed that no (non-bitfield) type is *smaller* than one byte and that one byte can hold at 256 distinct values, so if you have an `int8_t` and an `int16_t`, then it's guaranteed that `int8_t` is one byte, so `int16_t` must be two bytes.

Comment: This would be a perfect solution if the exact width types weren't unfortunately optional in the standard compliance.

Comment: @VilhelmGray they are optional to accommodate exotic platforms with `CHAR_BIT != 8` but C also says these types are required if your implementation has integer types of `8`, `16`, `32` and `64` bits.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard guarantees only that the size of  `char <= short <= int <= long <= long long` [and likewise for `unsigned`]. So, theoretically, there can be systems that have only one size for all of the sizes.

If it REALLY is critical that this isn't going wrong on some particular architecture, I would add a piece of code to do something like `if (sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)) exit_with_error("Can't do this....");` to the code.

In nearly all machines, `int` or `short` should be perfectly fine. I'm not actually aware of any machine where `char` and `int` are the same size, but I'm 99% sure that they do exist. Those machines may also have it's native `byte` != 8 bits, such as 9 or 14 bits, and words that are 14, 18 or 36 or 28 bits...

Comment: `9` bit is OK for `char` but not `7`, as `CHAR_BIT` is `>= 8`.

Comment: Yes, I said "byte", not "char" - on a 7-bit machine, CHAR may have to be 14 or 28 bit, to allow for 8 bits in a char.

Comment: the definition in C of a byte is not the same as the definition of an octet. A byte has `CHAR_BIT` bits.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the man page of [stdint.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html) (`uint_least16_t` for 2 bytes)

Comment: Couldn't a single C byte theoretically (albeit rarely) be 16-bits wide?

Answer (score 0):

At least according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types -- the size of an int is guaranteed to be two "char"s long.  So, this test should work, although I'm wondering if there is a more appropriate solution.  For one, with rare exception, most architectures would have their endianness set compile-time, and not runtime.  There are a few architectures that can switch endianness, though (I believe ARM and PPC are configurable, but ARM is traditionally LE, and PPC is mostly BE).

Answer (score 0):

A conforming implementation can have all its fundamental types of size 1 (and hold at least 32 bits worth of data). For such an implementation, however, the notion of endianness is not applicable.

Nothing forbids a conforming implementation to have, say, little-endian `short`s and big-endian `long`s.

So there are three possible outcomes for each integral type: it could be big-endian, little-endian, or of size 1. Check each type separately for maximum theoretical portability. In practice this probably never happens.

Middle-endian types, or e.g. big-endian stuff on even-numbered pages only, are theoretically possible, but I would refrain from even thinking about such an implementation.

Comment: Actually, I think big-endian (16-bit) `short` and `int` and middle-endian (software-emulated) `long` would not be too hard to implement.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer is basically "no", satisfying the interface requirements for the stdio functions requires that the range [0,UCHAR_MAX] fit in `int`, which creates an implicit requirement that `sizeof(int)` is greater than 1 on hosted implementations (freestanding implementations are free to omit stdio, and there's no reason they can't have `sizeof(int)==1`). So I think it's fairly safe to assume `sizeof(int)>1`.